# Can a plastic degrading bacteria project be recreated in a school lab environment?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology

I am looking for a science fair project and am wondering if this could be a good idea. I am in the 10th grade. I am not exactly sure of the materials needed since this is just the beginning stages of finding a project. From what I've researched, the main objective would be to isolate bacteria from soils, to test these isolates for ability to degrade different types of plastic and to identify these microbes. We have until December 14 to finish experimentation and would have help from a lab technician. Do you know if this type of project would be possible and what we should inform our lab technician with in order to help us? Please reply asap as we don't have much time left to find a project. Anything helps. Thanks!